# Could the Lightning Network encounter any problems as a result of Taproot activating?

Tags: lightning-network, taproot, soft-fork, activation-mechanism

I was reading this excellent [write up](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2021-November/019589.html) from Laolu Osuntokun on how the light client protocol Neutrino encountered a Taproot related issue on testnet. (Taproot is already active on testnet.)

Could the Lightning Network encounter [any problems](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110557/taproot-activates-within-the-next-2-weeks-what-could-go-wrong-and-what-could-be) as a result of Taproot activating? I'm leaning strongly towards no as unlike Neutrino no Lightning implementations as far as I know have been set up to deal with SegWit version 1 (Taproot) transactions (channel opens or channel closes spending to or from a Taproot multisig). And so the Lightning Network should not even notice that Taproot has activated?

I guess a large re-org due to miners initially mining an invalid Taproot spend could disrupt the Lightning Network but that would be blockchain related rather than related to a specific Lightning transaction(s).

Comment: I am a bit uncertain thus the comment: A chain split / fork might lead to strange situations as you would not be sure which asset you actually route. Initially both but newer channels would be anchored in either one of the chains. In particular channels opened before the split would have to be closed in both networks.